# how to query for greater than sort key in dynamodb with boto3

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a dynamodb table with string primary key called `name` and number sort key `age`. I want to get the items in the dynamodb table with `age` younger than 30. I understand that since my filter is on a Key, I can use query instead of scan.

So I tried:
    response = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('age').lt(decimal.Decimal(30))
    )
    response

But this returns the response:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query condition missed key schema element: name
```

So it looks like i need to provide a partition key for queries? Does this mean I can only make queries for age given a name?

What is the code to do this in boto3?

Comment: you are right, you can only make queries on range keys if you have the hash key.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's true. The `query` needs the partition key, as it runs on a specific partition only.

You need to use the `scan` and `filter` in your use case, but this can be a little expensive depending on the size of your table.

The ideal solution would be to keep track of all your partition keys and do parallel queries on them.